# Socket programing: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “1”

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm sending a message through UDP sockets and packets: The mesajes has the following format:

```
"MESSAGE" + SEPARATOR + "IDCLIENT"
```

Here is the code on the **Client**:

```
String msg = "MESSAGE" + SEPARATOR + id;
byte[] msgBytes = msg.getBytes();
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(msgBytes, msgBytes.length, serverIP, SERVER_PORT);

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.send(p);
```

Here is the code on the **Server**:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket ( SERVER_PORT );
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_MSG];
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket (buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(p);

// Here comes where my problem appears
String msg = new String ( p.getData() );
msg.trim(); //this is suposed to solve my problem, but it doesn't
String[] msgParts = msg.split(SEPARATOR);

if (msgParts.length == 2)
{
    String infoMsg = msgParts[0];
    int id = Integer.parseInt( msgParts[1] ); // Here the get the NumberFormatException
}

// Do more...
```

I don't understand the error messege: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"`. Because the String `"1"` should be converted to the Integer `1`, as far as I know.

*PS: I have ommited the try-catch staments for `IOException` for clarity.*

Comment: Change `msg.trim();` to `msg = msg.trim();`

Comment: What happens when you log or debug msgParts[1]? What exactly does it contain? Does it have quotes around the 1?

Comment: What is the value received in msg object?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you! What a stupid mistake. Sometimes you just need other people to see your code :)

Comment: @jpuriol, Remember that strings are immutable in java. So there is no function that changes the current state of a string, it always returns a new one

Answer (score 0):

Change `msg.trim();` to `msg = msg.trim();`
                    – Elliott Frisch